# How to bind enum on routes using scala?

Tags: scala, enums, playframework, routes, slick

I'm trying to receive some filter list as query param of a get request, which is also an enum on my controller. To do so, I'm using play framework with scala. The problem is: I can't putting the enum type as query param on it, because IDE doesn't recognize as a valid type.

So, I have something like this on routes file

`GET        /service-orders/ controllers.ServiceOrdersController.listServiceOrders(status: ServiceStatus)`

My enum file:

```
object ServiceStatus extends Enumeration {

  type ServiceStatus = Value

  val Pending = Value("pending")
  val Started = Value("started")
  val Completed = Value("completed")
  val Error = Value("error")
  
}
```

On build.sbt, I use this trying to inject package on routes file

```
  routesImport ++= Seq(
      "serviceOrders.models.ServiceStatus"
    ),
```

I tried a lot of things, but with no success. I read in some place that I could use `QueryStringBindable` function, but I can't did this works well... Can you guys please help me to solve this?

***Edit:*** Btw, there's a way to check if status is contained on a list of filters without making this?

```
.filter {
        serviceOrder =>
          status.map(serviceOrder.serviceStatus === _)
            .reduceOption(_ || _)
            .getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
      }
```

This was the only way I could thought to filter status by a list of filters received as query param from API.

Comment: You should rather have a look at [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#play-integration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `QueryStringBindable` instance like so:

```scala
package serviceOrders.models

object ServiceStatus extends Enumeration {

  type ServiceStatus = Value

  val Pending = Value("pending")
  val Started = Value("started")
  val Completed = Value("completed")
  val Error = Value("error")

  implicit val queryStringBindable: QueryStringBindable[ServiceStatus] =
    new QueryStringBindable[ServiceStatus] {
      override def bind(
        key: String,
        params: Map[String, Seq[String]]
      ): Option[Either[String, ServiceStatus]] =
        params.get(key).collect {
          case Seq(s) =>
            ServiceStatus.values.find(_.toString == s).toRight("invalid value")
        }

      override def unbind(key: String, value: ServiceStatus): String =
        implicitly[QueryStringBindable[String]].unbind(key, value.toString)
    }
}
```

In build.sbt you need this:

```
routesImport ++= Seq("serviceOrders.models.ServiceStatus._")
```

And this in your routes file:

```
GET     /some/route    controllers.SomeController.index(status: ServiceStatus)
```

Then you can create an `index` method that takes a `ServiceStatus` parameter in `SomeController` and Play will take care of the query parameters.

// edit:
You could actually use the `QueryStringBindable.Parsing` class to simplify the implementation further.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't test it yet, but it makes a lot of sense, and looks a nice solution for me. I will return with the result of this implementation on my project asap.